# How to pass a KeyValuePair to web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a List of KeyValuePairs from my angular service to my web api controller like so:

web Api controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Users([FromUri] List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> filters)
    { }
```

Angular service:

```
return $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                filters: [{ Key: "UserName", Value: "A.Lincoln" }]
            }
        });
```

I have tried lots of different ways to pass the params by changing the format of the json, but I always end up with the same result in te controller. filters = [0]{[,]}. So it knows I am passing it something but the key/value are always null. When I send a List of strings instead of keyvaluepairs it gets the values just fine. Can anybody help me with what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `JSON.stringify()` for your data property should suffice.

```
var jsonString = [
    {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Value": "A.Lincoln"
    }
]

$http.get(url, data: JSON.stringify(jsonString))
  .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the answer.
Is now deserialize the JSON string in the controller like so:

```
public IHttpActionResult Users([FromUri] string jsonFilters)
    {
        var filters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonFilters);}
```

If anybody knows a nicer solution please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the $resource service routes to a factory and use it in the controller through its methods, this will help you work more efficiently:

```
.factory('yourResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
      return $resource(url/:key/:value, { Key: '@key', Value: '@value' } {
        'get': {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        }
      });
    }]);
```

***THEN IN THE CONTROLLER***

```
  $scope.get= yourResource.get({Key: 'UserName', value: 'A.Lincoln'}, function (response) {
    alert(response);
  };
```